# Voiced/Unvoiced

Tags: произношение

Which consonant in a cluster determines whether the other consonant(s) is/are voiced? For example, if there is **зт**, is it pronounced **ст** or **зд**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latter one. **зт** is pronounced **ст.** Though I can't think of example, because if we are talking about prefixes **раз-**, **без-** they assume written forms **рас-**, **бес-** when preceding unvoiced consonants: *разливать*, but *раскрывать*, *безликий* but *бесхитростный.*

Comment: I was just thinking of an example of voiced/unvoiced clusters (perhaps within a word itself). Thanks for your answer!

Comment: If you need examples: *без толку*,  *ползти*, *замёрз-то* are all pronounced with **ст**