# Voiced consonants at the end of words

Tags: произношение

Generally voiced consonants become unvoiced when they're at the end of a word.

> **д**  is pronounced   **т**
>
> **б** is pronounced **п**
>
> **в** is pronounced **ф**
>
> **г** is pronounced **к**
>
> **ж** is pronounced **ш**
>
> **з** is pronounced **с**

Are there any exceptions to this rule?

Comment: Бог (god) is one of the exceptions. The final г is pronounced x.

Comment: It's not an exception to the rule. It's a remnant of the fricative "г" the word Бог used to be pronounced with. To this day some people will say "Слава Боhу" (with a fricative "г"), but not "Слава Боху".

Comment: I think it's an exception and a very interesting one. Thank you, Olga. I didn't know that.

Comment: Isn't the final /b/ in чтоб also always kept voiced?

Comment: @Olga, it's an exception but not to this rule. As Avi Gordon has mentioned, the devoicing rule applies to **бог** like it applies to any other word.

Comment: @AviGordon, I think you are arguing semantics.  Бог does not follow the general rule as formulated by the OP. Therefore, by definition, it is an [exception](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/exception). Why is it the case is a very different question.

Comment: @Olga, I still think yours is not a very good example as Бог effictively does NOT end in a voiced consonant (despite the spelling) whereas the discussed rule is unvoicing the voices consonants. So, as Sergey Slepov noted above, it's an exception but not to this rule.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if the next word starts with a voiced consonant (of those you listed), then the final consonant also becomes voiced, even if it was unvoiced: **кот был, код был** both have [д], while **кот стал, код стал** both have [т] before [с]. This only happens in continuous speech, when there is no pauses between the two words. See [Final-obstruent devoicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final-obstruent_devoicing#Russian).

Voicing and devoicing happens not only at word boundaries, but also at morpheme boundaries. E.g. in **посадка** the Д sounds like a Т and **сделка** is pronounced with an initial [з-]. See [Оглушение согласных](http://megabook.ru/article/%D0%9E%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85).

Also, if you want to 'spell out' a word, you could say e.g. **Глеб** with the voiced Б. This is the most common way of explaining how something is written, rather than spelling out individual letters.

Comment: for `кот был` it's an exaggeration, i heard some people do talk like this, but it's personal idiosyncrasy, originally voiced consonants may restore their voicing but the unvoiced ones never become voiced, if they do it's an accent

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка, see e.g. [this](http://megabook.ru/article/%D0%9E%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85).

Comment: See also https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/11949/2104

Comment: thank you, i concede that there's such a phenomenon and so retract my wholesale statement of `never`, yet the listed examples don't include ones such as `кот был`, where voicing occurs at the junction of two meaningful  words

Comment: I'd say that in `кот был` 'т' becomes a bit more voiced, but not as voiced as 'д' would be. And as for me, in other cases (including ones in listed example), unvoiced consonants are still less voiced than voiced ones, even if their voice is raised by their neighbours.

Comment: @SergeySlepov, I don't want to create another question, so I'll ask this here. I recently came across the word **конечно** and I noticed that **ч** is pronounced as **ш**, is this a special case?

Comment: @Trey, please raise a separate question. That's how this site works. I'll be easier for others to find.

Answer (score 1):

For more precision, we can say that obstruents (like the consonants you mention) devoice; but resonants (м, н, л, р) are exceptions in that they don't devoice in final position: so там, он, вал, and вор all end in voiced consonants.

That's admittedly a bit of a simplification - Jaye Padgett has a [paper](http://roa.rutgers.edu/files/528-0702/528-0702-PADGETT-0-0.PDF) where he mentions disagreement about the degree of devoicing of resonants, in section 2.3. But my sense is that's the overall tendency.

В is kind of marginal in that it does devoice in final position, but it doesn't cause voicing of a preceding consonant: свой [svoj], not *[zvoj].

Comment: Very interesting. Funny enough, in Polish /v/ itself devoices after a voiceless consonant: twarz [tfash] świąt [shfiont] twój [tfuj]. (sorry, I can't access the IPA at the moment).