# Pronunciation of Ч before Р

Tags: произношение

In **чрезмерно**, **чрезвычайный**, is the first **ч** pronounced the usual way, or rather [ш], like in *что*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pronunciation of конечно](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/15321/pronunciation-of-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be)

Comment: It's the usual way.

Answer (score 5):

It's pronounced the usual way.

The only subtle difference that some people pronounce very short **е** between **ч** and **р**, because it's hard not to do it)

Comment: This e  is a sign of uneducated speech. Аванесов, Орфоэпический словарь РЯ (1988). Черезвычайный с пометой "неправ."

Comment: Yes, this is misspelling, but I speak about mispronunciation. I know the right spelling, but it's hard to eliminate this sound completely

Comment: I think I get your idea. It's an awkward combination, some people may insert 'very short' sound in there. It's not about spelling though, it's a pronunciation dictionary (Резниченко И.Л. Орфоэпический словарь русского языка. - М., 2003 gives the same result) saying pronouncing 'e' is incorrect.